# writing a file finder (java)

Tags: java

I am writing an application which will search for for files with special filename extension on computer. (JPG for example). Input data: "D:", ".JPG" Output: txt file with results(file directories); I know one simple reccursive algo, but may be there is smth better. So, may be you tell me  an efficient algorithm to traverse the file directory. Also I want to use multithreading for solving this problem to make better performance. But how many threads should I use? If I will use 1 thread for 1 directory - this will be stupid.

Comment: If you do not want to reinvent wheels, you may use this http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

The recursive option you name is the only way to go, unless you want to get your hands dirty with the file system. I suspect you don't.

Regarding thread performance, your best choice is to make the number of threads configurable, create some sample directories, and measure performance for each setting.

By the way, most file-finders create an index of files. They scan the disc on a schedule, and update a file which contains the relevant information about the files and directories on disk. The file is in a format designed to facilitate searching. This index file is used to perform actual searches. If you're planning on repeatedly running this search against the same directory, you should do this.

Comment: The OP wants to find files, not index them. Indexing has its own drawbacks, and for a small app like this it's overkill.

Comment: I put the last paragraph as a side-note. Maybe that wasn't obvious.